# Why are only six HTTPS requests allowed to be sent simultaneously?

Tags: http, asynchronous, networking, https, xmlhttprequest

One of my front-end developer co-workers asked for my help because of the browser not sending HTTPS requests asynchronously. At least that is what he thought at first.
By opening up the Firefox networking tab, I realized that the requests get sent asynchronously, but for some reason, only six HTTPS requests are allowed to be sent parallel.

I assume this is a technical limit of the HTTPS protocol, though I do not know the cause.
I searched for the cause on the web, but I have not been able to find it so far.

In the following picture, the red parts of the lines mark the duration spent being blocked by another request:

[image]

Comment: Note that's *per domain*, the overall total is higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that this is a courtesy to the server you're connecting to. You wouldn't want to overload a server and prevent others from simultaneously connecting to it.

Depending on the browser, the limit changes as well.

See also: [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)